# Modal popover controller does not show its content when presented from viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I have a view controller, that is shown as a modal over another view controller. If it is presented with `animated:NO` from `viewDidAppear`, it does not show its content on the second time it is presented. I have minified the issue to this: I have added two controllers connected by a segue to the storyboard, each of them presents the same popover controller in `viewDidAppear`.
Each of them is an instance of the same class:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PopupViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self showPopover];
}

-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}

- (void)showPopover {
    PopupViewController* popoverController = [[PopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([PopupViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    popoverController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popoverController.preferredContentSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 20, 100).size;
    popoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    popoverController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds), 0, 0);
    popoverController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
    popoverController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:popoverController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

@end
```

The popover is presented correctly on the app launch, but is empty on pushing the second view controller, and on tapping back button. If I change `animated` to `YES`, the popovers are shown correctly.

Edit: If I debug view hierarchy in Xcode, the views are displayed correctly, with all their frames as they should be:

[image: View hierarchy]

This is how it looks like on the device (correct popover on the left and empty on the right):
[image: Example]

Comment: Does the popover get removed when you push the second view controller, perhaps in `viewDidDisappear`?

Comment: Before going to the second view controller I am dismissing the popover by tapping on the shadow around it

Comment: Are you waiting for the first popover to dissappear? Any warnings in your console?

Comment: @Sulthan, no warnings, first popover disappears completely.

Comment: I have reproduced your issue and I am still trying to find the reason for that behavior. It's possible to workaround that issue by adding a small delay (using `dispatch_after`) before showing the popover so it's probably connected with some problem in the view controller hierarchy. I have really bad experience with using popovers. They behave strange in many situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be reproduced easily. I started logging the events and it seems this is caused by the way `UINavigationController` is handling animations.

When `viewDidAppear` is called for the pushed controller, the animation is not finished yet. You can see that for yourself by checking the `navigationController:didShowViewController` method in `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

The event log looks like this:

```
Navigation controller will show VC 1
VC 1 did layout subviews
VC 1 did layout subviews
VC 0 did move to parent <UINavigationController: 0x7feaf181ec00>
VC 1 did appear
VC 1 did move to parent <UINavigationController: 0x7feaf181ec00>
Navigation controller did show VC 1
```

Note that the second controller is not even completely moved to the parent in `viewDidAppear:`.

The only viable workaround I have found is:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self showPopover];
    });
}
```

Which will let the navigation controller to finish its internal work.

Note the issue does not appear when pushing without animation so this is probably caused by the fact the we are trying to show a view controller without animation from another animation completion block and that means the order of view controller hierarchy events is broken. Adding the `dispatch_async` moves the code from the completion block and everything starts to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like this fixes the issue.